# Solving a right triangle (Trigonometry)

Tags: trigonometry

A highway has a gradient of 12.8% (i.e. it rises 12.8 m in 100 m horizontally). How much would a car rise (in m) if it drove 31 m along the highway?

Round answer to 2 decimal places.

Comment: What have you tried? If you are not familiar with the math, maybe you can draw a 0.1cm:1m model on paper for the 12.8m rise with 100m run case. Then check what happen when the car drives 31m along the road.

Comment: You need Pythagoras to work out the length of highway in the example. Then apply a simple ratio.

Answer (score 1):

#### Defining Variables

1. Let x represent how far the car moves in the horizontal direction
2. Let y represent how far the car moves in the vertical direction
3. Let h represent the hypotenuse of the right triangle formed by x and y
4. Let m represent the gradient of the highway

#### Goal

find y when:

1. h = 31
2. m =  12.8 / 100 = 0.128

#### Applicable equations

1. Gradient = rise / run = y / x
2. x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = h<sup>2</sup>   (Pythagorean theorem)

#### Plugging in known data into applicable equations

1. 0.128 = y / x or x = y / 0.128
2. x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = 31<sup>2</sup>

#### Plugging in equation 1 into equation 2 and solving for y

*any negative solutions are disregarded

$$(y / 0.128)^2 + y^2 = 31^2$$
$$(y^2 / 0.016384) + y^2 = 31^2$$
$$61.03515625y^2 + y^2 = 31^2$$
$$62.03515625y^2 = 31^2$$
$$y^2 = 31^2/62.03515625$$
$$y^2 = 15.4912159184$$
$$y = 3.93588819943$$
$$y ≈ 3.94m$$